# How to programmatically assign .ico files to the desktop shortcut for an Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've already done this for the icon that appears on the taskbar while the application is running. Now I'm trying to do this for the shortcut icon or application icon on windows (the icon you see when looking at all Windows programs/apps.)

I've read that this can be done with a .dll file, but I'm not interested in that.

My intuition is that this is not actually possible to do with VBA inside the .mdb. Hopefully I'm wrong. Looking for a discussion on possible solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Icons are displayed based on the application that is associated with the file extension.  What is the purpose of changing the icon?

Comment: It's a commercial product and we'd prefer our logo rather than the access logo. we currently do this by right-clicking the shortcut and changing it manually. We're looking for a programmatic solution

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/change-icon-of-a-shortcut-with-vba.976596/

Comment: Or this? http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/how-to-change-the-desktop-icon-for-an-excel-file-3690335

Comment: Another way is to write your own launcher.. which could also help you to find updates and then launch your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A windows shortcut does and can have a ico file specified for that shortcut. While "often" they point the shortcut to the .exe and the shortcut pulls out the ico contined INSIDE of the .exe, OFTEN you will and can specify the ico for the shortcut. And since in ALL cases your shortcut will actually point to msaccess.exe, then you have to create a custom shortcut with a ico specified. You could even manually build the shortcut, specify the ico and then just use VBA to copy that shortcut to the desktop (assuming the path name to your application is ALWAYS the same - often it will not be - if path name will change from user to user, then a installer is really the only practical way to solve this problem).

I not sure if you can set/create the shortcut in VBA, but I would suggest that you adopt a windows installer (or a free one like Inno). These installers will create shortcuts on your desktop, and allow you to specify the icon.

one free and popular installer (inno) can be found here:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Setting up icons and shortcuts on your desktop via VBA code and Access makes little sense since the user will not have yet run your application/VBA code to setup the shortcut in the first place!!! So use a installer for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into that installer. By chance, do you know of the program Advanced Installer? I've been using that recently and it appears capable. To me it seems like an installer is an installer; not much to it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a way to create a shortcut from VBA you can use the [CreateShortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.84).aspx) method of a WshShell object, e.g.,

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub CreateDesktopShortcutWithIcon()
    ' ref - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys(v=vs.84).aspx
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim strDesktop As String
    strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Dim oShellLink As Object
    Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\My Shortcut.lnk")
    oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\UCanAccessTest.accdb"
    oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
    'oShellLink.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Alt+f"
    'oShellLink.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"  ' for embedded icon
    oShellLink.IconLocation = "C:\__tmp\MIME\foo.ico"  ' for .ico file
    oShellLink.Description = "My shortcut created by VBA"
    oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
    'oShellLink.Arguments = "C:\myFile.txt"
    oShellLink.Save
End Sub
```